# Cannot access local subdomain

Tags: nginx

First of all, Im on mac os. And I modified /etc/hosts to look like this:

```
127.0.0.1 locaserver.com
127.0.0.1 api.locaserver.com
127.0.0.1 images.locaserver.com
```

As Im running nginx (installed with brew), I modified /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf to have this:

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error_log;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  images.locaserver.com www.images.locaserver.com;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8083;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  locaserver.com www.locaserver.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  api.locaserver.com;
        location / {
            client_max_body_size 20M;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        }
    }
    include servers/*;
}
```

Im runinng a react app on port 3000. And a nodejs on port 8081 (API). Before I added the new entry for images.locaserver.com everything worked as expected.
So when I went to locaserver.com:8080 I saw the react app. And when react app made requests to API, it did it at http://api.locaserver.com:8080.

So when I created a new node-app (images.locaserver.com on port 8083), the API is still working. However, the only way to access the images.locaserver.com is by going directly to the port number:

```
http://localhost:8083/
or even
http://images.locaserver.com:8083/
both work
```

What is wrong? I tried to move the entry for images.locaserver.com to be the first server, but it did not help.
When I go to http://images.locaserver.com:8080 then the react app takes over showing a page.

I looked into logs but no errors show up, as it is actually serving the page (the react one though).

Comment: So nginx is behaving the same as it was before you added the images.locaserver.com server block? Have you restarted/reloaded nginx?

Comment: Yes I restarted it.

Comment: And are you seeing the same behaviour as before you added the server block?

Comment: exactly. everything works. a part from accessing http://images.locaserver.com:8080 (which instead resolves to the react entry, i.e. port 3000).

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the computer solved the problem.